# How to dynamically generate a PayPal button with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, erb

I have an e-commerce website with many different products with different prices, and I want to allow people to buy them using PayPal. [This guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/create_payment_button/) details how to create a PayPal Buy Now button, but you have to manually fill out a form. This would be very very time consuming to do every time I add a product.

I looked at the HTML of the Buy Now button, hoping to be able to inject my product information with ERB, but nowhere in the HTML is the product information like price listed. Instead, there's a very long "value" element, and I assume the product information is encrypted within this.

Anyone know how to dynamically generate a PayPal button with Rails? If not, does anyone know of am alternative I could use?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the data as below:

ERB sample (in case you are sending one product):

```
   <li>
      <b>product name:</b> <%= @product.name %>
      <br>
      <b>product price:</b> <%= @product.price %>
      <b style='text-decoration: underline;'>Pay:</b>
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="yourbusinessmail@hotmail.com*">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<%= @product.name %>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<%= @product.id %>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%= @product.price %>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="<%= @product.shipping %>">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" >
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
    </li>
```

Use below Paypal website link to customize your button then you can inject values as in Ruby code:
[Design Paypal button](https://www.paypal.com/sg/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_singleitem-intro-outside)

Comment: Where did you find this solution?

Comment: @JoeMorano if you follow the link of paypal there is a button **Create your button**, it will generate the html tags to be added to your page. regarding ruby, it is the normal way of injecting code in ERB files.